# How does FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING interact with handles opened to communication devices?

Tags: windows, driver, createfile

Just as the title says, I am writing a networking program where I open a handle to a network driver using CreateFile, and I have been experimenting with the NO_BUFFERING flag.

Most documentation won't even mention this being used with communication devices, and the ones that do (AKA the MSDN reference, etc), simply mention that you can.

Does anyone have any idea how this may affect communication with the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a device driver implementation detail, options you specify in the CreateFile() call are passed in the [IRP_MJ_REQUEST request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The one I linked is the one for file systems, it is very fancy one.  Click through the IrpSp->Parameters.Create.Options link to [IoCreateFileSpecifyDeviceObjectHint()'s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Options argument to see FILE_NO_INTERMEDIATE_BUFFERING.

The documentation for the IRP_MJ_REQUEST for serial ports [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Very simple one, no arguments at all :)  In general, the winapi to device driver interface for communication ports is a *very* straight-forward.  There's an (almost) direct mapping between the documented winapi function and its [underlying IOCTL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The winapi function doesn't do much beyond basic error checking, then quickly passes the job to the driver.

So there isn't any way to pass the FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING option you specify so it simply doesn't get used.

Otherwise the logical conclusion, serial port I/O is interrupt driven, the driver *must* buffer in order to not lose bytes and keep an acceptable transfer rate.  You can technically tinker with the buffer sizes through [SetupComm()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but, as documented, it is only a recommendation with pretty high odds that the driver simply ignores very low values.

Comment: Wow, you opened up a whole new perspective for me! To recap: Does this mean that Windows itself doesn't actually buffer anything - the driver does? If so, some of the documentation on the web is wrong - I've found sites that explicitly says the flag prevents Windows from using it's own buffers!

Additionally, the networking driver is a TUN/TAP driver for windows, not a serial port per se. Does that affect anything? I imagine it would still be interrupt driven, but I need to ask to be sure!

Thank you much Hans,
-JN